# How do I make a variable unique constraint?

Tags: unique, conditional-statements

I in the table below, I need `scientific_name` to be unique except when `d_taxlevel_id = 7`. Then I need `scientific_name` and `d_taxgroup_id` to be unique. I am using PostgreSQL. Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
create table taxon( 
taxon_id int not null primary key,
parent_taxon_id int not null references taxon(taxon_id),
scientific_name varchar(100) not null,
d_taxgroup_id int not null references d_taxgroup(d_taxgroup_id),
d_taxlevel_id int not null references d_taxlevel(d_taxlevel_id)
    );

when d_taxlevel_id = 7
then 
unique_genus_in_taxgroup unique(scientific_name, d_taxgroup_id)
else
unique_non-genus_sciname unique(scientific_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use separate tables , one where you need unique and create a primary key accordingly. Second table would be for Id = 7 where you can allow duplicates